# How can I safely share environment variables with my team

Tags: firebase, github, environment-variables

I want to collaborate on a project with a colleague of mine, so I shared my private GitHub repository with them.

The problem is that my API keys are in an `.env` file and this `.env` file is included in the `.gitignore` file. Because of this, **they are not able to access the database and backend** (in Google Firebase), which we need them to, so we both can work in the same Firebase project.

Is there any way they can access my Firebase project without the need of me explicitly sharing my API key to them? Or does he have to copy all the API keys and Firebase project information in his own `.env` file?

Comment: I'd suggest you invite them as a collaborator so they can generate their own keys, rather than sharing yours. That way if they stop being a collaborator, it's easy to remove them again and their keys stop working.

Comment: @jonrsharpe it is not possible to generate user specific API keys in Firebase.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to add them to your Firebase Project. They can then copy the Firebase Config from the settings page into their own `.env`.
It is not possible to generate user specific API keys for Firebase.